# Backtrader - order.executed.value on sell order erroneous?

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, backtrader

Using a boiler plate strategy assuming 1 share being bought and sold (long only/ every buy order is coupled with a sell order).

For some reason when I sell a stock, it logs the value of the trade (shares * price) at the same amount that was established when the position was opened despite different share prices.

Output:

```
2018-02-15 10:30:00, BUY ORDER PLACED,    Price:  169.79, Cost:    0.00, Comm:    0.00
2018-02-15 10:30:00, BUY ORDER EXECUTED,  Price:  172.06, Cost:  172.06, Comm:    0.17

2018-03-19 14:30:00, SELL ORDER PLACED,   Price:  174.19, Cost:    0.00, Comm:    0.00
2018-03-19 14:30:00, SELL ORDER EXECUTED, Price:  174.88, Cost:  172.06, Comm:    0.17
```

Above we can see that the buy was executed at 172.06 (Trade value (i.e cost) is the same given ere trading 1 share), however, the sell order was executed at a different price (174.88) but still has the the same trade value and commission?

Sample Code:

```
class Test(bt.SignalStrategy):

    def __init__(self):
        self.sma1 = bt.ind.SMA(period=100)
        self.dataclose= self.datas[0].close    
        self.order = None 
        self.buyprice = None
        self.buycomm = None
        self.sellprice = None
        self.sellcomm = None

    def log(self, txt, dt=None):
        dt = dt or self.data.datetime.datetime(0)
        print('%s, %s' % (dt, txt)) 

    def notify_order(self, order):
        # 1. If order is submitted/accepted, do nothing 
        if order.status in [order.Submitted, order.Accepted]:
            return
        # 2. If order is buy/sell executed, report price executed
        if order.status in [order.Completed]: 

            if order.isbuy():
                self.log('BUY ORDER PLACED,    Price:{0:8.2f}, Cost:{1:8.2f}, Comm:{2:8.2f}'.format(order.created.price,order.created.value,order.created.comm))
                self.log('BUY ORDER EXECUTED,  Price:{0:8.2f}, Cost:{1:8.2f}, Comm:{2:8.2f}'.format(order.executed.price,order.executed.value,order.executed.comm))
                self.buyprice = order.executed.price
                self.buycomm = order.executed.comm


            if order.issell():
                self.log('SELL ORDER PLACED,   Price:{0:8.2f}, Cost:{1:8.2f}, Comm:{2:8.2f}'.format(order.created.price,order.created.value,order.created.comm))
                self.log('SELL ORDER EXECUTED, Price:{0:8.2f}, Cost:{1:8.2f}, Comm:{2:8.2f}'.format(order.executed.price, order.executed.value,order.executed.comm))
                self.sellprice = order.executed.price
                self.sellcomm = order.executed.comm

        self.bar_executed = len(self) #when was trade executed
    # 3. If order is canceled/margin/rejected, report order canceled
    elif order.status in [order.Canceled, order.Margin, order.Rejected]:
        self.log('Order Canceled/Margin/Rejected')

    self.order = None

def next(self):

    if self.order: 
        return

    if self.getposition(data=self.data).size == 0:
        if data.close[0] > self.sma1:
            self.buy()

    else:
        if data.close[0] < self.sma1:
            self.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your commission was probably set at 0.1% so in 
172.06 * 0.001 = 0.172 = 0.17 (rounded)
174.88 * 0.001 = 0.174 = 0.17 (rounded)

You get charged on the in and the out